# Text between script tags is highlighted in Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++

I am writing some HTML code in Notepad++, but for some reason, when I made the closing script tag, all of the lines within the two tags are white. This problem only occurs in this one file.

I am using the 'Material Theme' style configuration from [this Medium page](https://medium.com/@HiSandy/notepad-plus-plus-material-theme-2c3951e65e01), and I've tried removing the theme and re-adding it, but to no avail. This problem occurs across all files, but strangely only between script tags.

Here's what my problem looks like:

[image: What my problem looks like]

Why is this problem occurring? Is this a problem with the theme or with Notepad++? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't appear between `<script>` tags but INSIDE `<script>` it's normal behaviour, inside `<script>` tag, it is suppose to be javascript code, not html.

Comment: But it looks normal without the theme? Is there something missing from the theme that is leaving the stuff inside `<script>` tags white? Edit: Just realised that inside the theme, JavaScript's background colour wasn't the same as the others.

Comment: It don't use any theme and the code inside `<script>`, `</script>` has the same background color as your picture, not really white but something like very light blue/violet

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem - in the theme, JavaScript's style background colour isn't set to the same colour as all the others for some reason.